# Creating SQL bridge tables

Tags: mysql, sql, hash

If I have a Table A like below:

```
business_name   address  suburb   postcode      row_hash                  business_name_address_rn
Name 1        Address 1 Cranbourne  3045    223423dvdgfdfgdfg34353345bvb    1
Name 2        Address 2 Lynbrook    3045    345345345345dgbfgfg4545646tdf   2
```

And I create a Table B as the records that I believe are the singular and unique entities:

```
business_name   address      suburb   postcode  row_hash
Name 1         Address 1    Cranbourne  3045    223423dvdgfdfgdfg34353345bvb
Name 2         Address 2    Lynbrook    3045    345345345345dgbfgfg4545646tdf
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to apply that column row_hash from Table B to Table A as a new column?

thanks in advance

Comment: what do you mean by "Apply that row" ?

Comment: in table B I have a column called "row_hash". I was wondering if there's a way to compare two tables and populate the data as a new coolumn

Comment: What's the condition? As what we can see from the example tables above, both of them have identical data; except `business_name_address_rn` column; which table B don't have. Also, to make sure you really mean **column**, what would be the name of the new column? Or are you actually trying to populate **row**? Because adding column means modifying the table structure and adding rows is simply adding more data.

Comment: Hello,
Apologies if my questions confused you all. As you can see from my question I mentioned two columns (row_hash). I used a left join on the common columns(row_hash) to return different business addresses for the same business name(if any). Worked out well for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A left join on the common columns(row_hash) will return different business addresses for the same business name(if any).